# how to join 2 dictionaries on same keys in python

Tags: python, django, dictionary, nosql

I have 2 table of :

```
form(id, label, name)
```

and

```
subform(subid, formID (f.k) , subname)
```

In python, I'm trying to make a dictionary of join of these tables and i need a nested dictionary which for each id i could have another dictionary of subform(with related key),in format like:

```
{form:{"id":"1" , "subid":"11", subname:"test"}, label:"testlabel" , name:"testname"}
```

Do you know any solution to make this kind of Dictionary in python please?

Comment: Are you using models or dictionaries of already fetched data? It's already easier to use model/queryset methods if it can be done that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using django as specified in the tag and since you speak of **tables**, you should be able to do an inner join:

`SubForm.objects.all().select_related("form")`

The problem with your desired outcome is that the relationship you describe between your models is that of ONE Form TO MANY SubForm. Thus if you desire to do an inner join to your Form queryset, then you must do:

`Form.objects.all().prefetch_related("subform_set")`

where `subform_set` will be an array of subforms for each form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm using django but i d'ont use a model for these tables, i'm using sql query for getting this information from database directly

Comment: Then why use django at all?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, for who would need too i put my solution:

```
form = {},
subform = {}

For f in formTable:
    form[‘subform_id’] = subform
    form[‘label’] = f.label
    form[‘name’] = f.name

    For item in subTable:
        subform['form_id'] = f.id
        subform['subid'] = item.id
        sub['subname'] = item.name
```